# How do I exit the w3m help menu?

Tags: w3m

I'm using scrapy and just discovered the view command from the shell. It brings up the webpage in a very convenient instance of `w3m`. From `man w3m`, I learned that **H** brings up the help menu, but despite reading through it, I can't find the proper way to exit it.

I can do `C-h` which takes me back to history, but there must be a right way of exiting the help menu.

Comment: I don't seem to have w3m installed at the moment.. but have you tried `q`?

Comment: `q` offers to quit `w3m` instead. I managed to find an answer I'll add below.

Answer (score 13):

It turns out `B` is what you want, which goes back between buffers.

Comment: a related setting: `s    Pop up buffer-stack menu (SELECT_MENU)`

Answer (score 2):

Use Q. It will help you move out the program.